# How to create an array of all objects from many models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails 2.. I have a doubt.

In my application , i have 3 models like

Blog, Wiki , Media

I am trying to create an array like @final with all the blogs , wikis, medias posted under my application .

I have tried with

```
@blogs = Blog.all
@wikis = Wiki.all
@medias = Media.all

@final = []
@final << @blogs << @wikis << @medias
```

The above final array has 3 arrays in it..

But i am expecting to keep final array with the objects returned from 3 models

How to do so ?? 
PLease give suggestions

EDIT

I thing i tried is

```
 @final = []
 @blogs = Blog.all
 @wikis = Wiki.all
 @medias = Media.all
 @final = @blogs + @wikis + @medias
```

This is performing exactly what i need .. But its just listing all the blogs , medias and wikis. How to list all the entities based on the creation date of the particular object

Comment: please explain more what means: "to keep only one array with the objects returned from 3 models"

Comment: I think your sorting problem should go into another question. (Otherwise try with `order('created_on')`...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator, you want this:

```
@final = @blogs + @wikis + @medias
```

The [`<<` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000225) for an Array:

> Pushes the given object on to the end of this array.

whereas the [`+` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000271):

> Returns a new array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a third array.

You could also use [`flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280) if you were really attached to `<<` for some reason:

```
@final = (@final << @blogs << @wikis << @medias).flatten
```

but that would be a bit pointless. As noted by [powerMicha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831145/powermicha), you need to start the `<<` chain off with `@final` (or some temporary array) if you don't want to modify any of the `@blogs`, `@wikis`, or `@medias` arrays.

As far as sorting them goes, you could use [`sort_by!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000246):

```
@final.sort_by(&:created_at)
```

That assumes that you have the usual `created_at` method on the objects.

Comment: @mu is too short -- Hi i tried with + operator it worked . But how to list them based on the creation date of each object

Comment: @Jasmine: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. I've added an update to cover it.

Comment: What is the content of `@blogs` after `final = (@blogs << @wikis << @medias).flatten`? I think, this statement will lead to `@blogs = [ blog1, blog2, ..., [ wiki1, wiki2, ... [ media1, media2, ... ]]]`

Comment: @powerMicha: Yes, that will modify `@blogs` but `@final` will be right, I'll add an update to sort that out. Thanks.

Comment: @mu is too short -- How to apply the limit in the final array ??

Comment: @Jasmine: You could use [`slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000268), [`first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000222), or [`take`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000292) for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Array.flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280).

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this array
>   (recursively).

Answer (score 2):

With `<<` you are putting your arrays into an array. This is the same like:

```
@final = [@blogs, @wikis, @medias]
```

I suggest *mu is too short*'s answer to join your arrays

```
@final = @blogs + @wikis + @medias
```

See [API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000271)